# How to create image animation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an image animation which starts by clicking on `Start Animation` button and should alternate with another picture every half a second until I click on `Stop Animation` button. When I run this code, it does not output anything. what is wrong with the following code ?

My coding:

```
<button onClick="StartAnimation()">
Start Animation
</button>

<button onClick="StopAnimation()">
Stop Animation
</button>

<script>
    var counter;
    var Schedule;
    function StartAnimation(){
    var images = document.getElementById("fish"); 
   images.src="https://www.uow.edu.au/~dong/w3/assignment/a5/happy_fish.png";


    Schedule = setInterval(animationfunction,5000);

} 
function animationfunction(){
    var fish_img = document.getElementById("fish");
    fish_img.src = "https://www.uow.edu.au/~dong/w3/assignment/a5/sad_fish.png";
}
function StopAnimation(){
    clearInterval(Schedule);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've misnamed your function `function StarAnimation(){` should be `function StartAnimation(){`

Comment: You need to define where in the HTML the image is. you can see it working here: https://codepen.io/dotEthan/pen/xaJvXx

Comment: Yes, It is working in the link but the image should not be shown initially and image is not alternating. It just changes once and stops.

Comment: https://codepen.io/dotEthan/pen/RYYwmW

New pen. Image is hidden, then when you click start it adds a class called "on" which displays the image, waits 5 seconds and then turns on the sad fish. And it does just change once and then stop, the animation keeps running of course, that's why you have the "Stop Animation" button which stops it. 

If you want it to stop automatically, than just don't use the "Stop" button and put the clearInterval in the "animationfunction" function so it runs at the end.

Comment: Please include the code from the pen in your answer so that everyone can see your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Ethan but I dont want it to change the happy fish to sad fish only once. It must be changing every half a second means after every 0.5 second image will be changed. Sad Fish will keep on changing to Happy and Happy will change to sad every half second until I click stop.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this function.
Your code looks like, you only want to change your image once. Try to add loop or you can complete in one `if-else` statement like this.

```
function animationfunction(){

if(image == "happy"){
    image = "sad";
    fish_img.src = "https://www.uow.edu.au/~dong/w3/assignment/a5/sad_fish.png";
}else{
    image="happy";
        fish_img.src = "https://www.uow.edu.au/~dong/w3/assignment/a5/happy_fish.png";
}
}
function StopAnimation(){
    clearInterval(Schedule);
}
```